# Accessing Play configuration from Akka Actor

Tags: scala, akka, playframework-2.5

I have an Akka Actor in my Play app that accesses Play's configuration using a now deprecated method.

```
class MyActor (supervisor: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  val loc = Play.current.configuration.getString("my.location").get
  def receive = { case _ => }
}
```

if I do this:

```
import javax.inject._
class MyActor @Inject(configuration: play.api.Configuration) (supervisor: ActorRef) extends Actor {
```

My class won't compile and the compler returns: "classfile annotation arguments have to be supplied as named arguments"

I assume you can only DI the configuration within a controller class. So, is it possible to access the configuration from within an Akka Actore within a Play app? I could pass the configuration to the actor during construction or just have a separate config file for the actors, but both seem pretty hacky. Is there a preferred method using the Play api?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working in my project:

`Module.scala`:

```
class ExampleModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bindActor[ExampleActor]("example-actor-name")
  }
}
```

`Actor.scala`:

```
object ExampleActor {
  def props = Props[ExampleActor]
}
@Singleton
class ExampleActor @Inject()(/*some DI*/) extends Actor {
...
}
```

And you can then even inject that very actor into other Classes (the `@Named()` is optional if you have only one `Actor` configured) via *DI*:
`SomeOtherClass.scala`

```
@Singleton
class SomeOtherClass @Inject()(@Named("example-actor-name") exampleActor: ActorRef) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by mana above points out the most elegant way to use DI in combination with actors in Play, but within any Actor you can find the configuration like:

```
context.system.settings.config
```